# How to publish Created BOT on Composer to Azure and Make it available for end user?

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer

How to publish Created BOT on Composer to Azure and Make it available for end user?

I created a BOT using Composer and now I want to make it public OR make it available to end user .

Could you guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To publish your bot to Azure Web App and Azure Functions you'll need some prerequisites in addition to your bot:

- A subscription to [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/free/).
- [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

Then follow the rest of the article available in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-publish-bot#create-azure-resources)

You can also refer to the `README` file in your bot's project folder, for example, under this directory: `C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Composer\BotName`.

Comment: I am working in a corporate network where Azure CLI is not permitted to install on machine.

But I have Corporate Azure Account where I can access Azure services , So without Azure CLI on my machine , is it possible to publish it?

Comment: In this case, manually deploy Azure Web App and Azure Functions in Azure portal then follow the steps in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-publish-bot#deploy-bot-to-azure and in step 3 proceed with the Deploy to existing Azure resources option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-publish-bot#deploy-to-existing-azure-resources